# Set initial value for Picker in ViewModel in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Inside my Xamarin application I have added a Picker control to a page. The setup of that Picker looks like this in `xaml`:

```xml
<controls:ExtendedPicker x:Name="GenderPicker" Style="{StaticResource PickerControl}" Margin="0,0,0,20"
     ItemsSource="{Binding GenderItems}" 
     ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}" 
     SelectedItem="{Binding Gender, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

In my ViewModel I have this code to populate the picker with some values:

```cs
public class GenderItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class RegisterViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private DateTime _birthdate;
    public DateTime Birthdate { get => _birthdate; set => SetProperty(ref _birthdate, value); }

    public GenderItem Gender { get => _gender; set => SetProperty(ref _gender, value); }
    public List<GenderItem> GenderItems { get; set; } = new List<GenderItem>
    {
        new GenderItem { Naam = "Male" },
        new GenderItem { Naam = "Female" },
        new GenderItem { Naam = "Confused" }
    };

    public RegisterViewModel()
    {
        // This doesn't work
        Gender = new GenderItem { Naam = "Female" };

        // This works
        Birthdate = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-40);
    }
}
```

From within the `constructor` I try to set a default selected value for the `Picker` control. But for some reason the value isn't selected in the `Picker`.

I also set a `datetime` property with a value and I do see that this value is picked up by the Date control.

Why isn't this working for the `Picker` control? What can I do to make this work?

---

### SetProperty method

The `SetProperty` method lives inside my `BaseViewModel` class. You get this with every new Xamarin project.

```cs
    public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public IDataStore<Item> DataStore => DependencyService.Get<IDataStore<Item>>();

        bool _isBusy = false;
        public bool IsBusy
        {
            get => _isBusy;
            set => SetProperty(ref _isBusy, value);
        }

        string _title = string.Empty;
        public string Title
        {
            get => _title;
            set => SetProperty(ref _title, value);
        }

        protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T backingStore, T value,
            [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "",
            Action onChanged = null)
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingStore, value))
                return false;

            backingStore = value;
            onChanged?.Invoke();
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            var changed = PropertyChanged;
            if (changed == null)
                return;

            changed.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: `Gender` needs to be an element in `GenderItems`.  Right now you are creating a new object that has the same **value** as an item in `GenderItems`, but it is not the same object

Comment: @Jason Thanks, that was it. Can you post this as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Gender` needs to be an element in `GenderItems`. Right now you are creating a new object that has the **same value** as an item in `GenderItems`, but it is **not the same object**